# Kafka Streams Rocks DB Partitioning

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a requirement where I want to send expiring data to a long term database.  We are currently using the KeyValueStore and managing the old data our self.  I know there are WindowStores that will periodically delete old data.

Is there either a way to use the KeyValueStore but create a partitioned rocks db database and that we can manage which partition to put records to and delete. Or use the windowed store and intercept the process that deletes the partition so we can send that data where to go.

Comment: Kafka Streams stores are partitioned by default. However, I don't understand how partitioning relates to expiring old data (or actually to put it into an external store if it expires). For WindowedStores, it's not possible to intercept when data is deleted.

Comment: The state store partitioning, not topic partitioning.  I thought RocksDB puts everything in the default partition unless specified.  Based on what I am seeing my application is only creating one partition per RocksDB instance (if I have 20 treads/tasks,  I will have 20 RocksDb instances)

Comment: I guess there is some communication issue. What you call "RocksDB instance" is a "state partition" for me :) -- because a KTable is logical abstraction over a topic, the KTable state is shared and each shared is stored in one RocksDB. -- It seems, you are referring to "partitioning with one RocksDB instance" (ie, sub-partitioning of a shard)? Also, by "RocksDB partitions" do you refer to "column families"? -- For this case, there is no support to do anything like you ask for.

Comment: Yes, my terms were wrong (still learning).  With windows state stores when I record gets old what does streams delete?  A sub partitioning of a shard?

Comment: Window Stores are multiple RocksDBs per shard -- we call those Segments. If data is expired, we delete a whole segment by deleting the corresponding RocksDB.